# Spring defined map has bean names as key instead of specified key value

Tags: java, spring

I am trying a very simple thing that looks like it should work fine but I am getting some weird behaviour:

**Application-Context.xml**

```
<util:map id="transportMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport">
    <entry key="websocket" value-ref="websocketTransport" />
    <entry key="long-polling" value-ref="longPollingTransport" />
</util:map>
<bean id="cometDClient" class="com.client.CometDClient" />
```

Then in CometDClient.java:

```
@Inject
private Map<String, ClientTransport> transportMap;
```

However instead of ending up with a map with the mappings of `"websocket":websocketTransport, "long-polling":longPollingTransport`, I get `"websocketTransport":websocketTransport, "longPollingTransport":longPollingTransport`.

In other words the names of the **beans** are being used as my keys! Is there something I am doing wrong here? It looks like it should be idiot-proof enough even for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Resource(name = "transportMap")
private Map<String, ClientTransport> transportMap;
```

The issue is when Spring sees a Map being autowired, it injects in beans of that type into the field, with bean name as the key in the map. (same behavior with List, it would inject in beans of the type into the list). The fix will be to use @Resource, which forces a autowire by name.

Here is a quote from the Spring [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config):

> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name."

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything to test this with right now, so going out on a limb...

I think Spring only "sees" you asking for a map with `ClientTransport`-implementations as values, and places the bean names as keys, so it's not actually injecting the `transportMap` you define in the xml. You could try using

```
@Inject
@Qualifier("transportMap")
private Map<String, ClientTransport> transportMap;
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: @Qualifier could not be used to decorate a field apparently. Thanks for the answer though.